# vue-the-mask + element ui input slot 2 value error

Tags: element, directive, element-ui

anyone have the solution for below case ?

```
<el-input v-model="contactNo" v-mask="'## ### #####'" masked="true" /> // this is valid
```

I got the error, because v-mask directive requires 1 input, found 2

```
<el-input placeholder="enter phone number" v-model="contactNo" class="input-with-select"> 
    <el-select v-model="select" slot="prepend" placeholder="select">
      <el-option label="restaurant phone" value="1"></el-option>
      <el-option label="order phone" value="2"></el-option>
      <el-option label="personal phone" value="3"></el-option>
    </el-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove apostrophes from v-mask value or bind prop with `:`:

Option 1:

```html
v-mask="## ### #####"
```

Option 2:

```html
:v-mask="'## ### #####'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same problem in 2k23. Therefore, better late than never.

I checked the lib and in result can say - this is a library issue.

If the parent tag is not an input, then it searches for child tags, and if there are more than one, it throws an error, and if it is the only one, it continues to work. Why the developers done this decision is not clear, but unfortunately, the library is outdated and not supported. The only thing left is to forking it, or look for another solution.

How works it in the lib:
https://github.com/vuejs-tips/vue-the-mask/blob/master/src/directive.js

```js
if (el.tagName.toLocaleUpperCase() !== 'INPUT') {
  var els = el.getElementsByTagName('input')
  if (els.length !== 1) {
    throw new Error("v-mask directive requires 1 input, found " + els.length)
  } else {
    el = els[0]
  }
}
```

In my case, I separated the input and select.

```html
<el-input v-mask="'###'" placeholder="enter phone number" v-model="contactNo" class="input-with-select">
</el-input>

<el-select v-model="select" slot="prepend" placeholder="select">
  <el-option label="restaurant phone" value="1"></el-option>
  <el-option label="order phone" value="2"></el-option>
  <el-option label="personal phone" value="3"></el-option>
</el-select>
```